# How to create a custom site definition inherited from existing one?

Tags: 2013, custom, site-definition

I need to create new custom site definition which inherited from Publishing Portal with all features and functionality. What is the best way to do this in Sharepoint 2013?

Comment: Why would you inherit a site definition ? , and I don't think if it's even possible, you can always copy a existing site definition and then modify as you required.

Comment: Or use a WebTemplate, feeling more modern and fresh ;)

Comment: off course you would be better creating Web Templates then creating site definitions.

Comment: @RobertLindgren could you please explain why web template is better than site definition?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2011/07/22/site-definitions-vs-web-templates.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a site definition with Visual Studio 2012 taking the onet.xml in

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\PUBLISHING\XML\

as starting point and add your custom features, modules, pages or whatever in it.

Comment: I copied onet.xml from PUBLISHING\XML\ and deployed new custom site definition. When I was creating site collection based on this site definition I received such error: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: <nativehr>0x8107058a</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>The SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature must be activated at the site collection level before the Publishing feature can be activated.` Could you help me with this?

Comment: That error states that in the Site Collection settings you have to go to Site Collection Features --> Activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infraestructure. After it is activated try to create a new site with your customized site definition. If this doesn't work either, Save the out of the box publishing site as a template and use it in other sites

Comment: `you have to go to Site Collection Features --> Activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infraestructure` Do you mean root site collection? Because custom site collection can't create due to error. If yes, I have already done it and received the same error

Comment: I mean the top level site collection where the site is going to be created